# Internet Explorer's back button shows «processing»

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, iframe, back

I have a strange issue with Internet Explorer [sic!].

When navigating through my pages, the back-button alwasy shows «processing» as the last entry - and after that the pages I really accessed. I always have to click the back-button twice (at least) to make the browser access the last visited page.

The pages have some jQuery in it as well as a linked in follow-button (that sometimes shows < > instead of the button when I click the back-button).
The linkedIn-Button is added via Javascript and resides in an iFrame - and I read some posts that iFrames can break IE's back-button. Alas, when I remove the linkedIn-Button, the problem persists...

I might also add, that the page is called with https (which might cause other problems in IE?)

Any ideas???

Comment: I'm gonna hazard a guess that you have malware on your computer that is injecting bad stuff into your browser, causing this "Processing" entry in your history. Funny how 99% of the "problems" Internet Explorer has are caused by things other than Internet Explorer.

Comment: hmmm - I'm testing it on browserstack - and my customer has the same problem... Also, the problem doesn't exist in any other browser...